# html, javascript, Display button when if statement is true. Hide button if not true

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am wondering how I can display a button if a variable is a certain value.
For example: If the variable is at 5, display the button, but if the variable is at anything other than 5, hide the button. These are my two buttons inside of a div:

```
 <div style="z-index: 999; position: fixed">
        <button id="speedbtn">Change speed</button>
        <button id="jmpbtn">Change jump power</button>
      </div>
```

I want to display these buttons if a variable is set at 5. If the variable is at anything other than 5, hide the buttons.

Comment: This pure HTML, can you add the JavaScript around it which you have tried so far?

Comment: It's simple. - `let variable = 5; if (variable == 5) { any code } else { any code not var 5 }`. If the values are greater, then you can apply `switch`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here. Then, when you do post, we expect that you'll post what you've tried and a ***specific*** question about that attempt. If you are just looking to learn how to approach a problem, that's a job for Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if statement to check for the variable value and then update the display style for the buttons.

```js
var example = 6;

if(example === 5) {
  document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<div style="z-index: 999; position: fixed">
  <button id="speedbtn">Change speed</button>
  <button id="jmpbtn">Change jump power</button>
</div>
```

Comment: We tend not to provide answers to poor questions that don't belong here in the first place. We expect that OPs will do research and make an attempt at a solution before they post and when they do, they should include that attempt and ask ***specific*** questions about their problem. When you answer a poor question like this, you just attract more of them, which we don't want.

Comment: BTW: `""` is not a valid value for the `display` property. In your example, `""` should be replaced with `"inline"`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I'll make sure this from now.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var your_default_var = 5;
check(your_default_var);
function set(num){
 var yes_no = num;
 check(yes_no);
}
function check(your_var){
 if(your_var == 5){
document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "block";
}else if(your_var > 5||your_var < 5){
 document.getElementById("speedbtn").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jmpbtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="z-index: 999; position: fixed">
        <button id="speedbtn">Change speed</button>
        <button id="jmpbtn">Change jump power</button>
      <button onclick="set(6);">Set var to 6</button>
<button onclick="set(5);">Set var to 5</button>
<button onclick="set(4);">Set var to 4</button>
      </div>
```

Try this!

Comment: We tend not to provide answers to poor questions that don't belong here in the first place. We expect that OPs will do research and make an attempt at a solution before they post and when they do, they should include that attempt and ask ***specific*** questions about their problem. When you answer a poor question like this, you just attract more of them, which we don't want.

Comment: Ok I will try not to do that again